# Error with yarn.sh command

Tags: samba

There is an error comes up while I'm starting the `yarn.sh` command. This is the error output:

```
$ start-yarn.sh
starting yarn daemons
mkdir: cannot create directory `/logs': Permission denied
chown: cannot access `/logs': No such file or directory
starting resourcemanager, logging to /logs/yarn-hduser-resourcemanager-ubuntu.out
/usr/local/hadoop/sbin/yarn-daemon.sh: line 124: /logs/yarn-hduser-resourcemanager-ubuntu.out: No such file or directory
head: cannot open `/logs/yarn-hduser-resourcemanager-ubuntu.out' for reading: No such file or directory
/usr/local/hadoop/sbin/yarn-daemon.sh: line 129: /logs/yarn-hduser-resourcemanager-ubuntu.out: No such file or directory
/usr/local/hadoop/sbin/yarn-daemon.sh: line 130: /logs/yarn-hduser-resourcemanager-ubuntu.out: No such file or directory
localhost: mkdir: cannot create directory `/logs': Permission denied
localhost: chown: cannot access `/logs': No such file or directory
localhost: starting nodemanager, logging to /logs/yarn-hduser-nodemanager-ubuntu.out
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/yarn-daemon.sh: line 124: /logs/yarn-hduser-nodemanager-ubuntu.out: No such file or directory
localhost: head: cannot open `/logs/yarn-hduser-nodemanager-ubuntu.out' for reading: No such file or directory
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/yarn-daemon.sh: line 129: /logs/yarn-hduser-nodemanager-ubuntu.out: No such file or directory
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/yarn-daemon.sh: line 130: /logs/yarn-hduser-nodemanager-ubuntu.out: No such file or directory
```

Comment: It looks like your `start-yarn.sh` is not allowed to create a directory what leads to another errors like `No such file or directory`. Try running your file with `sudo` command.

Answer (score 2):

The script is attempting to create a directory called `/logs` and is failing because your user doesn't have the right to create that directory. The easy solution would be to run the script with `sudo`:

```
sudo start-yarn.sh
```

Note, however, that scripts have no business creating directories in `/`. What does this script do? Why would it need to create `/logs`? There is probably a variable you need to set in the script. Either post the script here, or look for a line that has something like:

```
PREFIX=""
```

That, or something similar, is probably present in your script and will allow you to set the base directory it will be working in. Set that to something like `~/yarn/` instead. You really don't want to be creating random directories in `/` and if that script is really doing so, I would even go so far as to consider it a bug.

Comment: Well, because I didn't read the first line of OP's output. Sorry!